# NativeQuery to queryBuilder impossible but i need querybuilder for my form entity type

Tags: forms, entity, query-builder, doctrine-query, nativequery

I have a sql query too complex to translate in QueryBuilder. It works by nativequery. The problem is that my entity type asks me a QueryBuilder not a query. Do you have a solution?

This is my query :

> SELECT v.*   FROM vat_rates v
>   INNER JOIN (
>   SELECT vr.code as
>   code2 , MAX(vr.dateIn) AS dateIn2
>   FROM vat_rates vr
>   WHERE vr.country = :country       AND vr.dateIn = :dateIn
>   GROUP BY code  ) 
>   AS max ON code2 = v.code AND dateIn =
>   v.dateIn;

And in my form type :

```
$builder->add('vat_rates', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'item_vat_rate',
                'class' => 'MyInvoicingBundle:VatRate',
                'query_builder' => function(VatRateRepository $cr) use ($options) {
                    return $cr->getListVatRate($options['country'],$options['dateIn']);                              
                },
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
            ))
```

Thanks you and sorry for my bad english.